# Specifying multiple metrics in EC2 Auto Scaling Group Target Tracking thru Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, aws-auto-scaling, terraform-aws-modules

I'm trying to implement the [EC2 Scaling on SQS queue size](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/ec2-auto-scaling-target-tracking-metric-math.html) example from the AWS docs, in Terraform. Using the [autoscaling module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/autoscaling/aws/latest) from terraform-aws-modules. I have successfully created the ASG (auto-scaling group) without the policy.

I tried adding the three metrics specified in the example:

```
  scaling_policies = {
    scale_on_sqs_queue_policy = {
      policy_type = "TargetTrackingScaling"
      target_tracking_configuration = {
        target_value = 100
        metric_data_queries = {
          expression = "m1 / m2"
          id = "e1"
          label = "Calculate the backlog per instance"
          return_data = true
        }
        customized_metric_specification = {
          metric_dimension = {
            name = "QueueName"
            value = "my-sqs-queue"
          }
          metric_name = "ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible"
          namespace = "AWS/SQS"
          statistic = "Sum"
        }
        customized_metric_specification = {
          metric_dimension = {
            name = "AutoScalingGroupName"
            value = "my_autoscaling_group_name"
          }
          metric_name = "GroupInServiceInstances"
          namespace = "AWS/Autoscaling"
          statistic = "Average"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

However, only the first `customized_metric_specification` is added by Terraform:

> module.my_autoscaling_group.aws_autoscaling_policy.this["scale_on_sqs_queue_policy"] will be created
>
> ```
> resource "aws_autoscaling_policy" "this" {    
>     arn                     = (known after apply)    
>     autoscaling_group_name  = "my_autoscaling_group_name"    
>     enabled                 = true    
>     id                      = (known after apply)    
>     metric_aggregation_type = (known after apply)    
>     name                    = "scale_on_sqs_queue_policy"    
>     policy_type             = "TargetTrackingScaling"    
>
>     target_tracking_configuration {
>         disable_scale_in = false
>         target_value     = 100
>
>         customized_metric_specification {
>             metric_name = "GroupInServiceInstances"
>             namespace   = "AWS/Autoscaling"
>             statistic   = "Average"
>
>             metric_dimension {
>                 name  = "AutoScalingGroupName"
>                 value = "my_autoscaling_group_name"
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

The metric math query is completely ignored too. This is also reflected in the AWS console:

[image: screenshot of the automatic scaling page of the foo auto-scaling EC2 group page. A box on the page reflects that only one GroupInServiceInstances metric is used.]

My question is, how do I use multiple metrics when defining a dynamic policy for an EC2 ASG in Terraform? It seems to be in [the spec](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/APIReference/API_CustomizedMetricSpecification.html) as multiple TargetTrackingMetricDataQuery objects.

I've also tried making `customized_metric_specification` an array or an object, which results in errors like this:

```
// [...]
target_tracking_configuration = {
  target_value = 100
  customized_metric_specification = {
    m1 = {
      metric_dimension = {
        name  = "QueueName"
        value = "my-sqs-queue"
      }
      metric_name = "ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible"
      namespace   = "AWS/SQS"
      statistic   = "Sum"
    },
    m2 = {
      metric_dimension = {
        name  = "AutoScalingGroupName"
        value = "my_autoscaling_group_name"
      }
      metric_name = "GroupInServiceInstances"
      namespace   = "AWS/Autoscaling"
      statistic   = "Average"
    }
  }
}
// [...]
```

> Error: Unsupported attribute
> on .terraform/modules/my_autoscaling_group/main.tf
> line 723, in resource "aws_autoscaling_policy" "this":
> 723:
> metric_name = customized_metric_specification.value.**metric_name**
> **customized_metric_specification.value** is object with 2 attributes
> This object does not have an attribute
> named "metric_name".

I consulted these sources before posting:

- The module's [GitHub repo](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-autoscaling) - I looked at the [code for the block](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-autoscaling/blob/e4ac55948cd2e6895ed41d859b6e91119761a12c/main.tf#L711-L730) and for any reported issues
- The Terraform [docs for the `aws_autoscaling_policy`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/autoscaling_policy) docs which seem to allow this
- Searched StackOverflow for "[terraform] multiple metrics autoscaling"
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70800812), however I haven't misspelt the key(s)

Comment: You have two keys in the metric with the same name at a first glance, so that is one thing to fix.

Comment: As in, two objects with the key `customized_metric_specification`? Or something else? @MarkoE

Comment: Yup, that was what I was thinking.

Comment: @MarkoE that would make sense, that the first block is overriden. [The code](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-autoscaling/blob/e4ac55948cd2e6895ed41d859b6e91119761a12c/main.tf#L711-L730) would make me expect that `customized_metric_specification` could be a set of objects, but I've not been able to make that work either - see the error message I attached above

Comment: It looks like the underlying [`aws_autoscaling_policy` resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/autoscaling_policy#customized_metric_specification) only allows one, too. I get this error: `No more than 1 "customized_metric_specification" blocks are allowed`

Answer (score 0):

Update: This functionality is available in v4.57.0 of the Terraform AWS Provider:

> resource/aws_autoscaling_policy: Add metrics to the target_tracking_configuration.customized_metric_specification configuration block in support of metric math

([source](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#4570-march--3-2023))

[See docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/autoscaling_policy#expression) for customized_metric_specification > metrics > expression

---

This functionality isn't supported in the underlying Terraform resources yet, which are made for Application Auto-scaling, not EC2 ASG. It's proposed to be added in [this PR](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/pull/28560) however.